# How to synchronize all browsing data (including history, bookmarks and passwords) between Chrome and Firefox in real time

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sync

Is there a gadget for Windows that would allow me to merge all browsing data between Firefox and Chrome in real time without having to manually export/import.
I save a password in Chrome and it automatically saves the password in Firefox (hence automatically fill the password for me in Firefox, even though it was saved by Chrome), the same with bookmarks and history (for the sake of omnibox autocomplete). Is such thing even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is not one tool / plugin which will do all of these things or at least not that I am aware of. There is plugins which can do parts of these however. For instance you could use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com) to sync passwords and [Papaly](https://papaly.com) to sync bookmarks. I am not aware of a plugin that will sync browser history.